# SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's NULLS FIRST?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

So Oracle has NULLS FIRST, which I can use to have null values sorted at the top followed by my column value in descending order:

```
ORDER BY date_sent NULLS FIRST
```

What is comparable in SQL Server?  There are these alternatives, assuming the date values are NULL or in the past:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(date_sent, GETDATE()) DESC
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t.setinactive IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), t.setinactive DESC
ORDER BY -CAST(date_sent as int) ASC
```

Any others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do some trick:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Order] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), [Order]
```

Comment: With this trick you can achieve any ordering you want. You can even mimic the more general IComparer interface found in many languages.

Comment: Keep in mind that this severely degrades performance, if you were previously using an index, since this now has to manually sort the results.

Answer (score 23):

The quick answer is this: the best solution for changing the ordering of nulls in the necessary cases is the accepted one. But you only have to use it, or a variation of it in the necessary cases:

- DESC + NULLS FIRST:

  `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Order] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), [Order] DESC`
- ASC + NULLS LAST:

  `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Order] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), [Order] ASC`
- ASC + NULLS FIRST: it works fine by default
- DESC + NULLS LAST: it works fine by default

Let's see why:

If you check the [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL) MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx), and scroll down to `ASC | DESC`, you can read this:

> ASC | DESC
>
> Specifies that the values in the specified column should be sorted in ascending or descending order. ASC sorts from the lowest value to highest value. DESC sorts from highest value to lowest value. ASC is the default sort order. Null values are treated as the lowest possible values.

So, by default if you specify `ASC` order, it works like `NULLS FIRST`. And, if you specify `DESC`, it works like `NULLS LAST`.

So you only need to do change the behavior for `NULLS FIRST` in `DESC` order, and for `NULLS LAST` in `ASC` order.

IMHO, the best solution for changing the ordering of nulls in the necessary cases is the accepted one, but I've included it adapted to the different cases in the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use Case/When statement, for example:

```
ORDER BY (case WHEN ColINT IS NULL THEN {maxIntValue} ELSE ColINT END) DESC

ORDER BY (case WHEN ColVChar IS NULL THEN {maxVCharValue} ELSE ColVChar END) DESC

ORDER BY (case WHEN ColDateT IS NULL THEN {maxDateTValue} ELSE ColDateT END) DESC
```

...and so on.

or even better as you don't care what is your column type and the max value.

```
ORDER BY (case WHEN ColAnyType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, ColAnyType DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have rows in your table with dates less than now, and other rows with dates greater than now, your NULLS would appear in the middle of the list.  Instead, you should probably use a value that will never sort in the middle of your list.

Order by IsNull(Date_Sent, '17530101') desc

Note:  That date is actually Jan 1, 1753.

Comment: Order by IsNull(Date_Sent, '17530101') desc would ensure my columns with a null date_sent value appear at the bottom, not the top.  You are correct, but I don't travel into the future to set the date_sent value =)

Comment: Good point, but the principle still holds.  You should use a value that will not naturally occur in your data.  Ex: Order by IsNull(Date_Sent, '99990101') desc

Comment: Totally agree on use of a sentinel value.

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative way when you want to adjust how nulls appear in the sort order. Negate the column and reverse your sort order. Unfortunately you would need to CAST dateTime columns.

```
ORDER BY -CAST(date_sent as int) ASC
```

Comment: Confirmed: Nulls are at the top, and non-null values are in DESC order.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ValueIsNull, Value1, Value2, Value3
FROM TableName
ORDER BY ValueIsNull DESC, Value1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(POSTING_DATE,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
 ,OTHER_FIELDS
```

Comment: Doesn't work - nulls are first, but the rest of the date_sent columns aren't sorted in DESC order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control this, to my knowledge.  And it looks like you have the correct approach with `ISNULL`.

With strings, I've used `ISNULL(field, '')` for the same purpose.

Comment: Kev: It all depends on the nature of the problem at hand.  The question was not "is this the ORDER BY clause to use in all cases?," and so G Mastros point is well-noted but not strictly on the critical path of the question itself.  rexem is looking for a more global way of controlling NULL sorting.