# Can I be more specific with SQL ordering?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  w.financial_year ,
        ISNULL(e.entity_name, 'Entity code ' + CAST(w.integer_1 AS VARCHAR) + ' is not available on the entity table. Please add.') ,
        COUNT(w.form_guid)
FROM    portal.workflow AS w
        LEFT OUTER JOIN property.entity AS e -- MS: Do not make inner join! Left outer join allows for exceptions to this case to be handled. Important as source data doesn't use property.entity
            ON w.integer_1 = e.entity_id
GROUP BY
        w.financial_year ,
        w.integer_1 ,
        e.entity_name
ORDER BY
        w.financial_year , e.entity_name
```

With my ordering I would like to show cases where e.entity_name was null first, and then sort the rest of the column alphabetically.. Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456653/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-nulls-first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course,

```
  SELECT w.financial_year,
    ISNULL(e.entity_name, 'Entity code ' + CAST(w.integer_1 AS VARCHAR) + 
        ' is not available on the entity table. Please add.') ,
    COUNT(w.form_guid)
  FROM portal.workflow AS w
     LEFT JOIN property.entity AS e
         ON w.integer_1 = e.entity_id
  GROUP BY case When e.entity_name Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End,
        w.financial_year, w.integer_1, e.entity_name
  ORDER BY case When e.entity_name Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End, 
      w.financial_year, e.entity_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN e.entity_name IS NULL 
             THEN 0 
             ELSE w.financial_year END 
        ,e.entity_name
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fe82/15)

Answer (score 0):

use NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST in clause ORDER BY like this:

```
SELECT  w.financial_year ,
        ISNULL(e.entity_name, 'Entity code ' + CAST(w.integer_1 AS VARCHAR) + ' is not available on the entity table. Please add.') ,
        COUNT(w.form_guid)
FROM    portal.workflow AS w
        LEFT OUTER JOIN property.entity AS e -- MS: Do not make inner join! Left outer join allows for exceptions to this case to be handled. Important as source data doesn't use property.entity
            ON w.integer_1 = e.entity_id
GROUP BY
        w.financial_year ,
        w.integer_1 ,
        e.entity_name
ORDER BY
        w.financial_year , e.entity_name NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: oh sorry, it's for Oracle. see [SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's NULLS FIRST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456653/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-nulls-first)