# Arranging the rows consisting Null Value columns either ascending Or Descending

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In **SQL** if selected column has more than one null value then how the server will decide which row consist of null value comes first and so on..... while arranging the all rows ascending or descending???...

**For Example:**

```
select * from emp order by comm;
```

Here if  "comm" column has more than 1 null value then within the null values how server will decide which row has to be first, which one is second with in the null values.
If any one knows plz raise your thoughts here.....

Thank you in advance........

Comment: maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456653/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-nulls-first

Comment: The server (mysql or mssql?) probably won't decide and throw the first row it finds. The same way if there are duplicate values other than `null`.