# Changing NULL's position in sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, null

I am sorting a table. The fiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51733/1).

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
field date NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
('2000-01-05'),
('2004-01-05'),
(NULL),
('2008-01-05');

SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY field DESC;
```

The results I get:

```
2008-01-05
2004-01-05
2000-01-05
(null)
```

However I need the results to be like this:

```
(null)
2008-01-05
2004-01-05
2000-01-05
```

So the NULL value is treated as if it is higher than any other value. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORDER BY DATE showing NULLS first then most recent dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to add an extra sort condition first:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field is null then 0 else 1 END,field DESC
```

Or, you can try setting it to the maximum of its datatype:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(field,'99991231') DESC
```

`COALESCE`/`ISNULL` work fine, provided you don't have "real" data using that same maximum value. If you do, and you need to distinguish them, use the first form.

Comment: Yes, the data is of a normal range and that is current days, years, (not more than +-10 years) :) Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The first option is my natural inclination.  I don't have access to a DB at present to test my assumption, but I would expect this; If the result-set is already naturally ordered, the latter will be planned with a more expensive re-ordering routine, due to the sort field being obfuscated by `ISNULL()`, and so the optimiser not being able to `know` about the relation between the datas natural order and desired final order.  *(Did that make any sense?)*

Answer (score 4):

Use a 'end of time' marker to replace nulls:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY ISNULL(field, '9999-01-01') DESC;
```

Comment: Um, you want the end of time, not the start of time, when ordering `desc` and wanting `null`s first

Comment: Aha! Here we go! Yet another day when I learn something valuable. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Be wary of queries that invoke per-row functions, they rarely scale well.

That may not be a problem for smaller data sets but will be if they become large. That should be monitored by regularly performing tests on the queries. Database optimisation is only a set-and-forget operation if your data never changes (very rare).

Sometimes it's better to introduce an artificial primary sort column, such as with:

```
select 1 as art_id, mydate, col1, col2 from mytable where mydate is null
union all
select 2 as art_id, mydate, col1, col2 from mytable where mydate is not null
order by art_id, mydate desc
```

Then only use `result_set["everything except art_id"]` in your programs.

By doing that, you don't introduce (possibly) slow per-row functions, instead you rely on fast index lookup on the `mydate` column. And advanced execution engines can actually run these two queries concurrently, combining them once they're both finished.