# Need to select first address in Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using *Access* in *Office 10* in a mixed *Windows 7 / Windows XP* environment.

I need to be able to select the current address for employees from a list. The problem I have is that the address `datefrom` could be *past*, *future* or *null*.

Removing future is obviously easy in the criteria, i.e. `WHERE datefrom <=date()`

The problem I have is that in the initial import of address data, most addresses did not have this information, and so the field is null.  An example of the data is below:  (date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`)

```
ID  EmployeeID  Postcode  DateFrom
1   1           AB12 3CD  [null]
2   2           GH12 5RF  [null]
3   1           CD34 5EF  10/03/2012
4   3           HA25 3PO  [null]
5   3           HA4  7RT  04/06/2012]
6   3           DB43 5YU  12/11/2011]
```

My desired output would be: (order of employees not important)

```
ID  EmployeeID  Postcode  DateFrom
2   2           GH12 5RF  [null]
3   1           CD34 5EF  10/03/2012
5   3           HA4  7RT  04/06/2012
```

I've tried sorting by `DateFrom DESC` which does order the list as below:

```
ID  EmployeeID  Postcode  DateFrom
3   1           CD34 5EF  10/03/2012
1   1           AB12 3CD  [null]
2   2           GH12 5RF  [null]
5   3           HA4  7RT  04/06/2012
6   3           DB43 5YU  12/11/2011
4   3           HA25 3PO  [null]
```

So if I could then just take the first result for each employee I'd be fine.  However I've tried (and failed) to do *SQL* including things like `DISTINCT`, `first()` and `GROUP BY`, but don't seem to be able to get anywhere.

I probably just can't see the easy obvious answer, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by like this:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [DateFrom] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
         [DateFrom] DESC
```

I found the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates) post. Please make sure to search first.

Comment: SQL is a generic term. CASE is not available in MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT Adr.ID, Adr.EmployeeID, Adr.Postcode, Adr.DateFrom
FROM Adr
WHERE (((Adr.ID) In 
  (SELECT Top 1 ID 
   FROM adr b 
   WHERE b.EmployeeID=Adr.EmployeeID 
   ORDER BY DateFrom DESC )));
```

The above is built using the query design wondow, so half the parentheses are unnecessary, however, if you are using the query design window, you may as well leave them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply update the `null` values to be a set date like `1900-01-01`?