# How do I make nulls comes first in a sort?

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc

When I order dates, sql puts nulls as the lowest value, but C# rdlc puts a null as the highest value. How do I solve it?

Comment: Google is your friend :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821798/order-by-date-showing-nulls-first-then-most-recent-dates

Comment: What is the column you are sorting data type?

Answer (score 2):

ANSI SQL and some databases support the `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST` keywords, just for this purpose.

Otherwise, you can use explicit logic in a SQL query:

```
order by (case when col is null then 1 else 2 end),
         col
```