# Visual Studio report sort zero as high

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2013, report-designer

I have a numerical field that I want to use to sort my report (in descending order). However, I want to show any zero values first.

Is there a way to sort zero first and then high to low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the idea I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/821856/266592) when researching a different issue, I was able to get this working.

Create an expression for the first sorting column, using a switch statement to sort zeros first:

```
= Switch( Fields!NumericAmount.Value = 0 , 0,
          1 = 1,                         , 1)
```

Then you add a second sorting column, picking your "NumericAmount" field in descending order.
This gives me my desired sorting order (0, 68, 64, 48, 3, 2, 1)!